# Ruby on rails update client with and without new password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a edit form for a client. It is also possible to change the password, but of course you don't want to change(and/or reenter) your password every time you change on of the other settings. To avoid updating the password I tried this:

```
def client_update_params
  if admin? == true
    params.require(:client).permit(:name, :email,:company_name,
                                 :address_street,:address_number,:address_city,
                                 :address_zip,:address_country,:billing_informations)
  else
    if params[:client][:password].blank?

      params[:client].delete("password")
      params[:client].delete("password_confirmation")

      params.require(:client).permit(:name, :email,:company_name,
                                 :address_street,:address_number,:address_city,
                                 :address_zip,:address_country)
    else

      params.require(:client).permit(:name, :email,:company_name,
                                 :address_street,:address_number,:address_city,
                                 :address_zip,:address_country,
                                 :password,:password_confirmation)
    end
  end

end
```

So the idea is to check if the password field is set or not. If it is set, update with new password, else do not update the password. But every time I hit submit(and leave the password field empty), the form validation says the password is to short....

Is there maybe a working/more elegant solution for this problem ?

EDIT:VALIDATIONS ON MODEL:

```
attr_accessor :is_admin_applying_update 
attr_accessor :plain_password

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i



before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

validates :email, presence: true, 
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

validates :company_name,presence:true

validates :address_street,presence:true 

validates :address_number,presence:true

validates :address_city,presence:true

validates :address_zip,presence:true

validates :address_country,presence:true

validates :billing_informations,presence:true

has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, :unless => :is_admin_applying_update

def Client.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def Client.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end


private

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = Client.encrypt(Client.new_remember_token)
  end
```

Comment: What validations are on the model?

Comment: As a side note, your VALID_EMAIL_REGEX isn't very valid. It allows `email@..c` for example. It even allows `.@..c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that you don't really have a `password` attribute in your model. The password is stored encrypted in a field named `password_digest`.

You should only be validating the `password` attribute when a password and a password_confirmation is given. You can do this in your model validation rather than deleting things from the params hash.

Also, you should validate the existence of a password_confirmation if password is present.

Answer (score 0):

Add a virtual attribute skip_password like the devise uses

In model

```
attr_accessible :skip_password

validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, :unless => :skip_password

def skip_password=(value)
   @skip = value
end

def skip_password
   @skip
end
```

In controller

```
@client.skip_password = true
```